Visual studio 2022 0xc0000005 after F5 (Debugging)
Ive installed fresh Visual Studio 2022 Community and .Net 8.0 SDK then created raw console project (C#). When Im trying to build it by hitting F5 (or just clicking >ConsoleApp1 on upper panel, no matter), the project builds, opens console, writes "Hello world!" and crashes Visual Studio.
I tried to reinstall both VS and .Net SDK, rebooted PC and tried to check other default projects - no unique results.
Big notice - when im trying to run the project without debugging (Ctrl + F5), no errors are showing up and vs code continues to run. Any ideas?






Guess something wrong with debugger and its access to memory. I have no any AV and any soft running in background

The error message says that the dlls cannot be found. Your Visual Studio may be missing the corresponding files.

@minxinYu-MSFT Yes I'm seeing this message about missing files. All the files from log are existing and located right in address set in log msg. All of them are not corrupted, I think so because I already tried to completely delete and reinstall Visual Studio. Tomorrow going to make a fresh Windows ISO installation, may be it will help huh

You can also try installing a different  Visual Studio version , such as a preview version.

It didnt work but thanks for help anyway sir! Glad to connect with you

Glad to know your problem has been solved! See Can I answer my own question?  Just a reminder :)

Reinstalled fresh Windows 11 without any tweaks. Just raw licensed ISO. And it works! Guess smth wrong with custom settings that comes from ISO provider. If u r getting same error - try sandbox raw VM Windows.
